# How to add dynamic div on that position where i clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an image zoom effect on my project. When the user clicks on that image I want image to be zoom. But the problem is that the div which I create dynamically is appended top of the body what I want is append this div above that image.
I try something like this:-

```
export const imagezoom = () => {
  const image = document.querySelectorAll(".zoom");
  image.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", zoom);
  });
};

function zoom(event) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const container = document.querySelector("body");
  div.classList.add("zoomDiv");
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = this.src;
  img.classList.add("zoomImage");
  console.log("added");
  div.appendChild(img);
  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```
.zoomDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.zoomImage {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: 11;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```
   <img class="zoom" src="../../../assets/Subject/physics/8.png" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do.

Put the image in a div. Make sure the image uses all the space in the containing div.
Set the position of that div to "relative".

Use

```js
var x = evt.pageX - $('#element').offset().left;
var y = evt.pageY - $('#element').offset().top;
```

To get the position of the mouse relative to the div container you put your image in. Make sure the dynamically generated image position to "absolute".

Use `x` and `y` to set the `left` and `top` CSS properties dynamically.

Comment: what is this #element ? i did't get it

Comment: That is the id of the div you put your image in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't probably think I understood what you are trying to do but according to this title *How to add dynamic div on that position where i clicked* try the following.
Add some JavaScript on your clickable image where you want to zoom

### Example

```
var x = document.querySelector('clickable_image');
x.addEventListener('click', e => {
    image.style.setProperty('--x',e.clientX + 'px');
    image.style.setProperty('--y',e.clientY + 'px');
});
```

and if you already done to set the above properties ad them in your CSS first of all add `position: absolute;` and add the following where `--y` is for `top` and `--x` for `left`

```
.clickable_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--y);
    left: var(--x);
}
```

the above will positioning that `div` to where you clicked